# CATransform3D.MakeScale is moving layer

Tags: ios

I am developing a Xamarin.Forms application for iOS. This app consists of an `UIView`, which has sublayers which are `CALayers`. They are added like this:

```
// draw all the pins from the list
foreach (var pin in _control.PinsSource)
{
    var point = new CGPoint
    {
        X = pin.Longitude,
        Y = pin.Latitude
    };

    var shapeLayer = new CAShapeLayer
    {
        Name = nameof(MapItem),
        Path = MakeCircleAtLocation(point, PinRadius).CGPath,
        FillColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor
    };

    Layer.AddSublayer(shapeLayer);
}

// Create a UIBezierPath which is a circle at a certain location of a certain radius.
private static UIBezierPath MakeCircleAtLocation(CGPoint location, nfloat radius)
{
    var path = new UIBezierPath();
    path.AddArc(location, radius, 0, (float)(Math.PI * 2.0), true);
    return path;
}
```

Then I have a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` which can scale the `UIView` and some other `GestureRecognizers` like panning.

Scaling and panning the base view works well. The `UIView` is scaled using a variable called `_currentScale`. See the full scale method here:

```
private void HandlePinch(UIPinchGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    // Prevent the object to become too large or too small
    var newScale = (nfloat)Math.Max(MinZoomLevel, Math.Min(_currentScale * recognizer.Scale, MaxZoomLevel));

    if (_currentScale != newScale)
    {
        _currentScale = newScale;

        Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(_currentScale, _currentScale);

        foreach (var subLayer in Layer.Sublayers)
        {
            if (subLayer.Name == nameof(MapItem))
                subLayer.Transform = CATransform3D.MakeScale(PinRadius / _currentScale, PinRadius / _currentScale, 1);
        }
    }
    recognizer.Scale = 1;
}
```

If the sublayer is a map pin, I did like to **NOT** scale it with the `_currentScale`, so that's why I am dividing the scale using `PinRadius / _currentScale`.

The scaling is working fine, however the pin is moving across the map which is weird. See here:

[image: Screen recording]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find another way then recreating a new `CAShapeLayer` on every pinch. It's very ugly, but it's working.

```
private void HandlePinch(UIPinchGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    // Prevent the object to become too large or too small
    var newScale = (nfloat)Math.Max(MinZoomLevel, Math.Min(_currentScale * recognizer.Scale, _maxZoomLevel));

    if (_currentScale != newScale)
    {
        _currentScale = newScale;
        _currentPinRadius = _pinRadius / _currentScale;

        Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(_currentScale, _currentScale);

        // First layer is a CALayer, so start at 1
        for (var i = 1; i < Layer.Sublayers.Length; i++)
        {
            var caLayer = ((CAShapeLayer)Layer.Sublayers[i]);

            var cgPoint = new CGPoint
            {
                X = _control.PinsSource[i - 1].Longitude,
                Y = _control.PinsSource[i - 1].Latitude
            };

            caLayer.Path = CreateCircle(cgPoint, _currentPinRadius);
        }
    }
    recognizer.Scale = 1;
}
```